# No IEEE b/g/n and internet connection is very slow

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I installed Ubuntu 16.04. The WLAN is working using a built-in driver, but the IEEE configuration of b/g/n is not running although my WLAN supports b/g/n. I am using Realtek mini-pci adapter and my driver is wlx7cc7095af019. Also the internet connection is very slow.

How do I solve it?

[image: no wireless]

[image]

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:065e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0461:4e2a Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: there is no out put at all

Comment: Then post output of `lspci` and `lsusb` TO YOUR QUESTION AS TEXT.

Comment: Please do not post terminal output to comments. Post it to your question.

Comment: i already edit it

Answer (score 0):

This is a RTL8723BU USB chipset.

You can install a driver this way. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
sudo modprobe -r rtl8xxxu
```

This will create a `rtl8723bu` directory in your Home folder.
Open `Makefile` in that directory and insert a `#` symbol before `EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE`.

Then run

```
cd rtl8723bu
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v 8723bu
```

That should enable your adapter.

If you get "Required key not available" that means that you are using UEFI with Secure Boot enabled. You will need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

To make it permanent blacklist `rtl8xxxu` module by

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8xxxu.conf <<< "blacklist rtl8xxxu"
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

**Note:** You will have to run the three last commands after each kernel upgrade to re-install the driver unless you install it using DKMS to automate the process.

Comment: last output appear this "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8723bu': Required key not available" after i enter sudo modprobe -v 8723bu in terminal

Comment: You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: done disabling it, but the old driver still running and in used

Comment: How do you know which driver is used? `wlx7cc7095af019` is not a driver.

Comment: You can check the driver by `usb-devices | awk '/b720/' RS=`

Comment: I check it at network properties UI ssid i've connect. After i put this command "sudo lshw -C network". Wireless network configuration only show rtl8xxxu driver, not the rtl8723bu. It is because of the kernel or anything.

Comment: if anything not help, what would you suggest the best linux distro for my wifi running smoothly

Comment: It does not depend on a distro. You can run `sudo modprobe -r rtl8xxxu && sudo modprobe 8723bu`.

Comment: Does it need to reboot or not. After entering the command, nothinng output is shown. Is it like that or not.

Comment: No, you don't need to reboot. To keep it after a reboot some extra actions are needed.

Comment: what are the actions?

Comment: You will need to blacklist the old driver and maybe add the new one to initrd. Does the Wi-Fi work better with the new one?

Comment: Yes, it run better and use rtl8723bu driver. But the wireless configuration is unassosiated.

Comment: How to blacklist the old driver or add new one to initrd.

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: what is the  "edit... –", it is a  link to another ubuntu support or changing the file system.

Comment: I edited my answer and added what you asked for.

Comment: Don't forget that after a kernel upgrade you will need to re-install the driver. And accept the answer by cliciking the check sign at the left.